# Variables comparison

Tags: javascript

I have this simple problem with Javascript where I want to compare two variables, but somehow it doesn't work correctly. I even checked that the types of variables are the same. Please help.
Specifically, I get alerts for numbers, and I even get the alert for current counter is 5 total is 5, although I would expect it to enter the "then".

```
function fun(idCount, finalCallback) {
this.idCount = parseInt(idCount);
var counter = 0;
var strings = {};
this.register = function(str, id) {
    counter++;
    strings[parseInt(id)] = str;

    if(counter == this.idCount) {
        alert("Going to override");
        //blabla
    } else {
        alert("Current counter is: " + counter + " Total " + idCount + ". Types: " + typeof counter + " and " + typeof idCount);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Remember to include the radix parameter to `parseInt`: e.g. `parseInt(id, 10)`

Comment: Since they are numbers anyway, I believe that I don't really need to do the parse anyway.But how can it be that the numbers are obviously the same, yet the comparison fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
function fun(idCount, finalCallback) {
    var self = this;
    this.idCount = parseInt(idCount, 10);
    var counter = 0;
    var strings = {};
    this.register = function(str, id) {
        counter++;
        strings[parseInt(id, 10)] = str;

        if(counter == self.idCount) {
            alert("Going to override");
            //blabla
        } else {
            alert("Current counter is: " + counter + " Total " + idCount + ". Types: " + typeof counter + " and " + typeof idCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using self did the trick. But can you please explain why? I read up on what self means (context switches), but if I actually display the variables, the values seem to be the same. So how come?

Comment: In JavaScript objects are created using function. So if you refer `this `inside any function it refers to that function itself. In your case if you access idCount inside the function this.register, it will display the value but this.idCount does not. Hope you are clear.

Comment: Thanks! One step closer to understanding Javascript. Ah, the pain! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to point that if you use == it doesn't matter if both objects are same type or not.

Example:

```
"0" == 0 // true
```

To force type comparison as well use **===**

```
0 === 0 // true
```